# Multiple If condtion in gridview itemtemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, itemtemplate

I am using below code in gridview to show the status of the product. I have three status in gridview. I got the error "The name 'eval' does not exist in the current context"

```
<%# ((string)eval("fld_status") == "0") ? "~/images/arrow_yes.png" : ((string)eval("fld_status") == "1") ? "~/images/edit_msg.png" : "~/images/arrow_down.png" %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# is case sensitive language...so both eval and Eval is different...and the method for binding is Eval not eval..so you can try like this

```
<%#  ((string)Eval("fld_status") == "0") ? "~/images/arrow_yes.png" : ((string)Eval("fld_status") == "1") ? "~/images/edit_msg.png" : "~/images/arrow_down.png" %>
```